# Apply Filter function to select multiple rows of a CSV in D3.js

Tags: javascript, csv, parsing, d3.js, filter

I have a data table with the following format:

```
    Month,KPI,Type,Unit,S40401,S40402,S40403
    JAN,A,Units FTP,PC,2000,4000,6000
    JAN,B,Invoice Sales FTP,EUR,2000,4000,6000
    JAN,C,Gross Sales Actual FTP,EUR,2000,4000,6000
    JAN,D,Net Sales FTP,EUR,2000,4000,6000
    JAN,E,CMC FTP,EUR,2000,4000,6000
    FEB,A,Units FTP,PC,2000,4000,6000
    FEB,B,Invoice Sales FTP,EUR,2000,4000,6000
    FEB,C,Gross Sales Actual FTP,EUR,2000,4000,6000
    FEB,D,Net Sales FTP,EUR,2000,4000,6000
    FEB,E,CMC FTP,EUR,2000,4000,6000

...
...
...
```

If that data contains only one variable/KPI (e.g. one out of A-E), there´s no problem at all to parse the data into a D3-Chart. But since I want to select specific rows, it gets complicated. I can´t adapt the CSV file, the data has to be in this structure. So my only solution is filtering by rows.

How can I filter the data using .filter() to parse specific rows?
For example: Filter the data in a way that only the "A-rows" or "B-rows" from 
 column "KPI" are selected?

I suppose this part of the code where the CSV is imported needs the filter function. I already tried but no success:

```
<script>
var freqData;
d3.csv("export.csv", function(data) {
    data = csv.filter(function(row) {
        return row['KPI'] == 'C';
   freqData = data.map(function(d) { return {
        Month: d.Month, 
        freq: {
            S40401: +d.S40401,
            S40402: +d.S40402,
            S40403: +d.S40403
        }}
    });
  dashboard('#dashboard',freqData);
});

</script>
```

Below the whole code:

```
<script>
function dashboard(id, fData){
    var barColor = 'steelblue';
    function segColor(c){ return {S40401:"#04B404",S40402:"#045FB4",S40403:"#B40404"}[c]; }

    // compute total for each state.
    fData.forEach(function(d){d.total=d.freq.S40401+d.freq.S40402+d.freq.S40403;});

    // function to handle histogram.
    function histoGram(fD){
        var hG={},    hGDim = {t: 60, r: 0, b: 30, l: 0};
        hGDim.w = 500 - hGDim.l - hGDim.r, 
        hGDim.h = 300 - hGDim.t - hGDim.b;

        //create svg for histogram.
        var hGsvg = d3.select(id).append("svg")
            .attr("width", hGDim.w + hGDim.l + hGDim.r)
            .attr("height", hGDim.h + hGDim.t + hGDim.b).append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + hGDim.l + "," + hGDim.t + ")");

        // create function for x-axis mapping.
        var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, hGDim.w], 0.1)
                .domain(fD.map(function(d) { return d[0]; }));

        // Add x-axis to the histogram svg.
        hGsvg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + hGDim.h + ")")
            .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));

        // Create function for y-axis map.
        var y = d3.scale.linear().range([hGDim.h, 0])
                .domain([0, d3.max(fD, function(d) { return d[1]; })]);

        // Create bars for histogram to contain rectangles and freq labels.
        var bars = hGsvg.selectAll(".bar").data(fD).enter()
                .append("g").attr("class", "bar");

        //create the rectangles.
        bars.append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
            .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
            .attr("height", function(d) { return hGDim.h - y(d[1]); })
            .attr('fill',barColor)
            .on("mouseover",mouseover)// mouseover is defined below.
            .on("mouseout",mouseout);// mouseout is defined below.

        //Create the frequency labels above the rectangles.
        bars.append("text").text(function(d){ return d3.format(".3f")(d[1])})
            .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d[0])+x.rangeBand()/2; })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1])-5; })
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle");

        function mouseover(d){  // utility function to be called on mouseover.
            // filter for selected state.
            var st = fData.filter(function(s){ return s.Month == d[0];})[0],
                nD = d3.keys(st.freq).map(function(s){ return {type:s, freq:st.freq[s]};});

            // call update functions of pie-chart and legend.    
            pC.update(nD);
            leg.update(nD);
        }

        function mouseout(d){    // utility function to be called on mouseout.
            // reset the pie-chart and legend.    
            pC.update(tF);
            leg.update(tF);
        }

        // create function to update the bars. This will be used by pie-chart.
        hG.update = function(nD, color){
            // update the domain of the y-axis map to reflect change in frequencies.
            y.domain([0, d3.max(nD, function(d) { return d[1]; })]);

            // Attach the new data to the bars.
            var bars = hGsvg.selectAll(".bar").data(nD);

            // transition the height and color of rectangles.
            bars.select("rect").transition().duration(500)
                .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d[1]); })
                .attr("height", function(d) { return hGDim.h - y(d[1]); })
                .attr("fill", color);

            // transition the frequency labels location and change value.
            bars.select("text").transition().duration(500)
                .text(function(d){ return d3.format(".3f")(d[1])})
                .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d[1])-5; });            
        }        
        return hG;
    }

    // function to handle pieChart.
    function pieChart(pD){
        var pC ={},    pieDim ={w:250, h: 250};
        pieDim.r = Math.min(pieDim.w, pieDim.h) / 2;

        // create svg for pie chart.
        var piesvg = d3.select(id).append("svg")
            .attr("width", pieDim.w).attr("height", pieDim.h).append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate("+pieDim.w/2+","+pieDim.h/2+")");

        // create function to draw the arcs of the pie slices.
        var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(pieDim.r - 10).innerRadius(0);

        // create a function to compute the pie slice angles.
        var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function(d) { return d.freq; });

        // Draw the pie slices.
        piesvg.selectAll("path").data(pie(pD)).enter().append("path").attr("d", arc)
            .each(function(d) { this._current = d; })
            .style("fill", function(d) { return segColor(d.data.type); })
            .on("mouseover",mouseover).on("mouseout",mouseout);

        // create function to update pie-chart. This will be used by histogram.
        pC.update = function(nD){
            piesvg.selectAll("path").data(pie(nD)).transition().duration(500)
                .attrTween("d", arcTween);
        }        
        // Utility function to be called on mouseover a pie slice.
        function mouseover(d){
            // call the update function of histogram with new data.
            hG.update(fData.map(function(v){ 
                return [v.Month,v.freq[d.data.type]];}),segColor(d.data.type));
        }
        //Utility function to be called on mouseout a pie slice.
        function mouseout(d){
            // call the update function of histogram with all data.
            hG.update(fData.map(function(v){
                return [v.Month,v.total];}), barColor);
        }
        // Animating the pie-slice requiring a custom function which specifies
        // how the intermediate paths should be drawn.
        function arcTween(a) {
            var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
            this._current = i(0);
            return function(t) { return arc(i(t));    };
        }    
        return pC;
    }

    // function to handle legend.
    function legend(lD){
        var leg = {};

        // create table for legend.
        var legend = d3.select(id).append("table").attr('class','legend');

        // create one row per segment.
        var tr = legend.append("tbody").selectAll("tr").data(lD).enter().append("tr");

        // create the first column for each segment.
        tr.append("td").append("svg").attr("width", '16').attr("height", '16').append("rect")
            .attr("width", '16').attr("height", '16')
            .attr("fill",function(d){ return segColor(d.type); });

        // create the second column for each segment.
        tr.append("td").text(function(d){ return d.type;});

        // create the third column for each segment.
        tr.append("td").attr("class",'legendFreq')
            .text(function(d){ return d3.format(".3f")(d.freq);});

        // create the fourth column for each segment.
        tr.append("td").attr("class",'legendPerc')
            .text(function(d){ return getLegend(d,lD);});

        // Utility function to be used to update the legend.
        leg.update = function(nD){
            // update the data attached to the row elements.
            var l = legend.select("tbody").selectAll("tr").data(nD);

            // update the frequencies.
            l.select(".legendFreq").text(function(d){ return d3.format(".3f")(d.freq);});

            // update the percentage column.
            l.select(".legendPerc").text(function(d){ return getLegend(d,nD);});        
        }

        function getLegend(d,aD){ // Utility function to compute percentage.
            return d3.format("%")(d.freq/d3.sum(aD.map(function(v){ return v.freq; })));
        }

        return leg;
    }

    // calculate total frequency by segment for all state.
    var tF = ['S40401','S40402','S40403'].map(function(d){ 
        return {type:d, freq: d3.sum(fData.map(function(t){ return t.freq[d];}))}; 
    });    

    // calculate total frequency by state for all segment.
    var sF = fData.map(function(d){return [d.Month,d.total];});

    var hG = histoGram(sF), // create the histogram.
        pC = pieChart(tF), // create the pie-chart.
        leg= legend(tF);  // create the legend.
}
</script>

<script>
var freqData;
d3.csv("dataset_sales.csv", function(data) {
   freqData = data.map(function(d) { return {
        Month: d.Month, 
        freq: {
            S40401: +d.S40401,
            S40402: +d.S40402,
            S40403: +d.S40403
        }}
    });
  dashboard('#dashboard',freqData);
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You werent closing your functions and you werent filtering on your data.
You loaded your data as `data` and then ran your filter function on `csv`.
The below should do what you are looking to do

```
var freqData;
d3.csv("test.csv", function(data) {
    filteredData = data.filter(function(row) {
        return row['KPI'] == 'C';
    });
    freqData = filteredData.map(function(d) { 
        return {
            Month: d.Month, 
            freq: {
                S40401: +d.S40401,
                S40402: +d.S40402,
                S40403: +d.S40403
            }
        }
    });
    console.log("freqData", freqData);
});
```

Output:

```
[{
  "Month": "JAN",
  "freq": {
    "S40401": 2000,
    "S40402": 4000,
    "S40403": 6000
  }, {
  "Month": "FEB",
  "freq": {
    "S40401": 2000,
    "S40402": 4000,
    "S40403": 6000
  }
}]
```

​​